# How to get all xml values from array using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following `java xml file` which is having `array and level=1 and length=3`,
I `tried using for-each` but `how to get all values upto length =3 ?`

input xml -

```
<field name="demoCon">
          <array class="com.demo.xml.Message" length="3" level="1">
            <object class="com.demo.xml.Message">
              <field name="myCode">
                <value class="java.lang.String">123</value>
              </field>
              <field name="Name">
                <value class="java.lang.String"/>
              </field>            
            </object>
           <object class="com.demo.xml.Message">
              <field name="myCode">
                <value class="java.lang.String">456</value>
              </field>
              <field name="Name">
                <value class="java.lang.String"/>
              </field>            
            </object>
          <object class="com.demo.xml.Message">
              <field name="myCode">
                <value class="java.lang.String">789</value>
              </field>
              <field name="Name">
                <value class="java.lang.String"/>
              </field>            
            </object>
          </array>
        </field>
```

xslt i tried with following code -

```
<demoCon>     
              <xsl:for-each select="field[@name= 'demoCon']/array[@class='com.demo.xml.Message']/object[@class='com.demo.xml.Message']">

                <xsl:variable name="var:DemoName2" select="@name" />
                <xsl:variable name="var:DemoValue2" select="value/text()" />

                <myCode>
                  <xsl:if test="string($var:varName2)='myCode'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var:varValue2" />
                  </xsl:if>
                </myCode>
                <Name>
                  <xsl:if test="string($var:varName2)='conditionName'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var:varValue2" />
                  </xsl:if>
                </Name>

              </xsl:for-each>
            </demoCon>
```

am i missing something I guess yes level=1 and length = 3 in above xslt code.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT has defined variables called `var:DemoName2` and `var:DemoValue2`, but in your `xsl:if` statements you test for `$var:varName2` and use `$var:varValue2`.

I don't think you need to worry about using variables here. You can simplify the code to this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="field[@name= 'demoCon']/array[@class='com.demo.xml.Message']/object[@class='com.demo.xml.Message']">
  <myCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='myCode']/value" />
  </myCode>
  <Name>
    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Name']/value" />
  </Name>
</xsl:for-each>
```